# Serialization and deserialization of objects based on Primary keys

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, deserialization

I have several related objects, say, user and location. User and location have a one to one relation

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=500)
    last_name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=500)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

while working with [django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/), a get request on users will return something like

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "first_name": "first_name",
  "last_name": "last_name",
  "location": 34
}
```

I would like to get a response to something similar to,

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "first_name": "first_name",
  "last_name": "last_name",
  "location": {
    "id": 34,
    "name": "No Man's Land"
  }
}
```

Nested serializers and PrimaryKeyRelatedField work but not in all situations.
Is there a way this is achievable?

Comment: Nested serializer is the way to go though, can you add the code that you tried and what specific case isn't working for you? Now it's vague what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: This works when getting resources. When trying to edit (by submitting the location pk) I get 'non_field_errors'. Any work around?

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to achieve your desired result would be with a nested serializer. That is to write a serializer for your nested bit, and then use that as a field within you parent serializer. Something like this:

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(null=True, max_length=500)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(null=True, max_length=500)
    location = LocationSerializer()
```

Comment: Thanks, This works when getting resources but fails when editing resources. I get 'non_field_errors.' any work around?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write custom create and update methods for this. Check below code and update it according to your requirement

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
           model = Location
           fields = '__all__'

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     location = LocationSerializer()

     class Meta:
          model = CustomUser
          fields = '__all__'

      def create(self, data):
           location = data.pop('location', None)
           # Write your code if location is new or already there here 
           if location is new:
               location = Location.objects.create(**location)
           elif location is not new:
               location = get_location
           user = CustomUser.objects.create(**data, location=location)
           return user
       
       def update(self, instance, data):
           location = data.pop('location', None)
           if location:
               if location is new:
                   location = Location.objects.create(**location)
               elif location is not new:
                   location = get_location
               instance.location = location
           instance.save()
           return instance
```